# Delayed Table Name Resolution in View

Tags: db2, db2-400

I have a view over a table. It turns out the table gets moved and an updated version of it created each night. This ensures there is always a table of the expected name present in the database, but I cannot find a way to make my view continue to point to the current version of the table. Whichever table existed when the view was created is the one I end up pointing to even after it moves and goes stale.

ViewA:

```
select a, b, c from todays_table;
```

`todays_table` stays current all day, then at night it gets renamed to `todays_table01`. View A now points to `todays_table01` and a new table shows up called `todays_table`. Again, `todays_table` is current, but `ViewA` no longer is.

Is there a way to delay the table name resolution until the view is used? I haven't been able to get `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` working for `SELECT` statement. I think I could get a dynamic SQL statement working if I used a cursor, but I have never needed these before and I'm not sure if they are the right path. I read about `AUTO_REVAL` but I believe this would only delay resolution until the first time the view was used and still go stale that night.

I could, of course, stop using the view and just move the complex query into my program but there are many places it is needed so I would like to eliminate all other solutions before falling back to this.

It would be ideal to eliminate the temporary table and just have the master table receive updates throughout the day but this is beyond my comprehension as I know nothing about RPG II and OCL.

Thanks for reading.

**Edit**
Per @Mr. Llama's suggestion, I experimented with using synonyms and aliases to point to `todays_table` and then having my view point to the synonym. Unfortunately in this scenario, the view uses the alias to resolve the actual table name on creation so the view continues to point to `todays_table` when it is renamed to `todays_table01`, though the alias continues to reference `todays_table`.

**Edit 2**
I'm accepting @mustaccio's answer because it does work and would be a reasonable approach to this problem if I could get the parameters going where they need to. My particular project requires flexibility so I am actually going to jump on the nightly process bandwagon and add a program to recreate my views after the process messes with their references as @danny117 suggested.

Thanks to everyone who replied though, I learned a lot about how all of these pieces work together.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a synonym.  Make the view point to a synonym, then update the synonym to point to the current "active" table.

Comment: Get into the process that creates the new daily table and create the view there.

Comment: Create and replace the view before each use.

Comment: I really appreciate both of your responses. 
@Mr. Llama I tested synonyms and aliases out a bit but they behave as I expected - they also follow `todays_table` when it gets renamed rather than continuing to point to the name. It also appears that writing a view pointing to a synonym or alias resolves the actual table name on creation rather than continuing to reference the synonym.
@danny117 Creating the view before each use ranks above putting the query directly into my code, though I had hoped for a better solution. The process is a huge mess of OCL, RPG II, CL, and RPG/400 - I'm afraid...

Comment: Correction to my comment, the synonym continues to point to the right place but the view doesn't since it appears to resolve to the actual table name on view creation. Sorry for the misinformation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be able to achieve what you want by wrapping your view definition in a SQL table function, something like

```
CREATE FUNCTION insteadofview (<parameters>)
RETURNS TABLE (<columns>)
...
RETURN
  SELECT <the rest of your view definition>
```

Depending on how you query your view, you will probably need to pass search criteria into the function as parameters, otherwise performance will be suboptimal because the function will have to return all rows from the query before search arguments can be applied.

[According to the manual](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafzrena.htm), as you have noticed views on a table that is renamed continue to point to the original table *object*. Routines, however, including table functions, will be invalidated and their plans prepared again when they next invoked, using the original source table *name*.

I have no way of testing this though.

[Full syntax to create a table function](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafzcftb.htm).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This does work! I can even make a view for the UDTF so the user doesn't have to be concerned with the details. The downside, as you mentioned, is performance. When I change the view to be a shell pointing to the UDTF, my query takes about 14 seconds. When the UDTF is not involved, the same query takes first 5 seconds, then 2.9 on subsequent executions as the query optimizer kicks in. The query optimizer doesn't seem to know what to do with the UDTF (understandable). Performance would be better, I'm sure, if I added parameters to the UDTF as suggested.